# How to invoke static method from C# class without creating instance

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly myAsm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Some.dll");
            Type myService = myAsm.GetType("SomeClass");
            String s = (String) myService.InvokeMember("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod  | BindingFlags.Public,
    null, null, new object[] {"MyParam"});
        }
    }
```

In Some.Dll there is public static Method SomeMethod with String param returning String 
but I get method missing Error...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the `BindingFlags.Static` flag.

```
String s = (String) myService.InvokeMember("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod  | BindingFlags.Public,
null, null, new object[] {"MyParam"});
```

Answer (score 6):

If your method is static you should use this binding flags:

```
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
```