# Returning a class (not an object) from a property / method in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, return-type

I'm writing a library, where I want properties on the `Main` class to return a *class*, so that class methods can be called via chaining.

`Main main = new Main()
main.Foo.Bar()`

I will also have properties on `Main` to return *object* instances as well.

`Main main = new Main()
main.Foo("name").Baz()`

This will allow me to keep all related functionality in a single class, but to expose only the methods that are available within each context.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but why wouldn't nested classes within `Main` accomplish what you're after?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you need to be more clear about what you want `Foo` and `Foo()` to _do_.

Comment: Look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp)

Comment: Do you mean returning a Type? Then use typeof (YourType). To invoke static methods without an instance of that type, look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119353/how-to-invoke-static-method-from-c-sharp-class-without-creating-instance However, interfaces can't define static methods, so unless you know which type you are expecting, you can't invoke it's static members. (At least not without more runtime reflection)

Comment: I read the article you reference and I think a lot of the confusion comes from the author's misuse of the term "class", which you then carried to this question. A class is code which defines and implements the behaviors a custom type. You cannot call methods of a class. An object is the concrete instantiation of an instance of a class. You can call methods on an object. The method chaining technique (also called fluent design) described by the author of the article is a technique of having the methods of an object return the next object needed in the chain.

Comment: Your notion of "returning a class" in .NET will most likely be interpreted as "returning a type", and you wouldn't be able to "chain calls". I think what you meant was: you want to return an *object*, instead of returning a *primitive, built in type*? Are you talking about [fluent interfaces](http://rrpblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=33), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

example usage:

```
Dim main As New Main
main.Foo.Bar.SomeMethod()



Public Class Main

    Private m_Foo As Foo = New Foo()

    Public Property Foo As Foo
        Get
            Return m_Foo
        End Get
        Set(value As Foo)
            m_Foo = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class Foo

    Private m_Bar As Bar = New Bar

    Public ReadOnly Property Bar
        Get
            Return m_Bar
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Public Class Bar

    Public Sub SomeMethod()

    End Sub

End Class
```